# Unable to find reason behind App crash on release mode in a single specific device

Tags: android, crash

I understand that it is a very broad question and not really about sharing code.
It is about the steps that one should follow logically to find out the reason behind a specific crash.

**Google Play Console also does not report the crash. So I have no Crash/ANR Stacktrace to refer here.** Let me explain what I am facing exactly.

The app was working perfectly in that user's device till a week back and all operations including the task where the crash is happening was working smoothly. But suddenly while performing that task one fine morning, the app crashed and has been crashing on that step ever since.

What have I tried??

I asked the user to uninstall and reinstall the app. Didn't work..

I asked the user to clear cache and data from the device and then uninstall and reinstall the app. Didn't work

I removed all data of the user from Firebase (where my data is kept). Then asked him to  remove data locally, uninstall and then reinstall. Still didn't work

The app is working absolutely fine in other devices and have not got any report from any other user so far.

Question: What more can I do? What might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

does your app contain crashlytics?

if yes, look into crash log from crashlytics.
if no, then add crashlytics, upload a new update and then ask the user to update and crash the app.

Then check the crash log in crashlytics in firebase console.

Comment: No I don't. I will try this suggestion